# How to make a decision what widget to show based on it size in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to implement a widget that makes a decision what child to display based on available size and size of children. It should iterate though children and display first that can be fitted inside.

```dart
Column(children: [
  Expanded(child: SomeWidget([expandedWidget, shortWidget])),
  Text('some text'),
  Spacer()
]);
```

Is it possible to implement `SomeWidget` in a such way, that it can decide whether to use `expandedWidget` if there is enough space or `shortWidget` if `expandedWidget` can't fit.

`LayoutBuilder` widget doesn't have size of children, so I am not sure it can be used for it.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look to [MediaQuery widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html)

You could do something like :

```dart
var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
if (height < someValue) {
    return shortWidget;
} else {
    return expandedWidget;
}
```

Comment: But I need to make a decision based on `expandedWidget` size as well.